# Change Readonly or disabled on JQuery

Tags: html, jquery

```
  <td role="gridcell">input</td>
  <td role="gridcell">1</td>
  <td role="gridcell">
    <input class="remove1" type="button" value="▼" style="margin: 4px">
    <input id="Txt_test" class="txtBox" type="textbox" value="220" style="margin: 4px">
    <input class="Add1" type="button" value="▲" style="margin: 4px">   
    </td>
  <td style="display:none" role="gridcell">
  </td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr class="k-alt" role="row">
    <td role="gridcell">input</td>
    <td role="gridcell">2</td><td role="gridcell">
    <input class="remove1" type="button" value="▼" style="margin: 4px">
    <input id="Txt_test" class="txtBox" type="textbox" value="59" style="margin: 4px">
    <input class="Add1" type="button" value="▲" style="margin: 4px">
      
    </td>
    </tr>
      
    </tbody>
```

top was my out put Html

**Then i using JQuery to change below code to disable or readonly but it didn't work!**

```
<input id="Txt_test" class="txtBox" type="textbox" value="220" style="margin: 4px">
```

**I Try on JQuery**

```
$("#Txt_test").attr('disabled', true);
```

and

```
$("#Txt_test").prop('readonly', true);
```

I have change input type="text" same error for me.

Comment: `id` attributes in the DOM have to be unique. You have repeated `#Txt_test` multiple times, so only the first element is recognised. You need to use a class instead.

Comment: But I use $(".txtBox").attr('disabled', true);
also cannot disabled it

Comment: Works fine in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ozu7kwjh/

Comment: but on my code didn't work , Because of i use on Kendo ui?

Comment: this is my GridCells

Comment: The fact this is being created through a Kendo grid changes things entirely. I'd suggest starting a new question, explicitly stating you're using Kendo, and also stating the exact conditions/event you're using to set the fields to readonly/disabled